# how can i access a parent view controller's view from a child view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I have a main view controller that takes care of the drawing for my 2D opengl ES view, and a child view controller buttonManager that determines what buttons to load and draw during launch.

Once the user presses on one of these buttons, this view controller is created and its view is supposed to come up, but the view never gets added but has been tested to work. Heres my code from the main view controller:

```
 buttonManager=[[ButtonManager alloc] init];
 [self addChildViewController:buttonManager];
 [self.view addSubview:buttonManager.view];
```

and heres my code to launch this view:

```
-(void)launchStopDialog: (NSString*)stopName {
    NSLog(@"stopdialog should be launched.");
    if (stopDialogController == nil)
        stopDialogController = [[StopDialogController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StopDialog" bundle:nil];
    if (stopDialogController)
        [stopDialogController presentWithSuperview:self.view.superview withStopName:stopName]; 
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To access the parent View controller you can use `self.parentViewController`. Once you have it you can access its view simply by using its `view` property

Comment: In Swift 3.0 use `self.parent`
"Yeah! Swift 3.0, %$^%!" (c) Breaking Bad

Comment: @aqs : why is self.parent *nil* in ViewDidLoad ?

Comment: @Kashif, just check the next answer.

Answer (score 29):

Note to those using iOS 5.x+

`self parentViewController` now returns `nil`. You will now have to use `self presentingViewController` to achieved the same result. See this blog post for more information and additional work arounds for upgrading your code base: http://omegadelta.net/2011/11/04/oh-my-god-they-killed-parentviewcontroller/

Comment: The link isn't broken for me.

Answer (score 4):

Now after they have killed the

```
self.parent
```

you can use

```
override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?)
{        
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it is because I'm creating the child view programmatically or the `self.parent` or `self.presentingViewController` no longer work, but the `didMove` method was the only solution that worked for me. (And that I'm calling the `childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)` when adding the child view)

Answer (score 3):

here's what worked for me:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSString * segueName = segue.identifier;
    if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"child-view"]) {
        ChildViewController * childViewController = (ChildViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this using the objective c blocks approach. Take a look at this blocks tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FS4JAy1Wy3w